# Does the oracle has a limit when get the Blob?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, blob, limit, jmeter

I am writing a Java program to get the BLOB from Oracle (byte by byte).
and I am using the Jmeter to run the java program.
When I was simulating two users run the Java program at the same time, the response time of getting the BLOB is almost twice of the time when one user run the Java program.

Does oracle have any output limit at the same time?

Here is the Java code:

```
BLOB blob = rs.getBLOB(BLOB_COLUMN_NAME);
in = blog.getBinaryStream();
while((byteValue = in.read())!=-1) {
    ////////
}
```